# Scribus: coloring SVG

Tags: color, print-design, svg, scribus, spot-color

Is there a way to use `SVG` graphics in `Scribus` and set a colors for it? I need to use a self named spot color in terms of printing business cards with partial refinement. But `color` properties for SVG are greyed out :-/

[image: s]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import the SVG, ungroup everything repeatedly, until all parts are separate.

[image]

Select an element. Open the properties, and select a colour.

[image]